# What is the purpose of passing in a type into the TypeDescriptor.GetConverter method?

Tags: c#

In the code below, although I am getting a typeconverter for type Person, but I could also use it for the type Dog. (The types Person and Dog have nothing to do with each other.)

```
    var person = new Person {Name = "Foo", Age = 99, Ssn = Guid.NewGuid()}; 
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof (Person));
    string str = converter.ConvertToInvariantString(new Dog());
    Console.WriteLine(str);//ConsoleApplication1.Dog
```

So what is the purpose of passing in a type int the GetConverter method?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. There's no guarantee that the converter you get is useful for `Dog`s, but that doesn't mean that you'll get any error message if you do end up using on `Dog`s anyway. In other words, your code doesn't help to illustrate the question you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type type) overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtxwhzx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives more options to the developer. MSDN states:

> Call this version of this method only when you do not have an instance of the object.

So you should use the [TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Object o)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w202c8fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whenever possible.

Scott Hanselmann has a good example in his blog article [TypeConverters](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx) - he uses this method for a generic type identification:

```
public static T GetTfromString<T>(string mystring)
{
   var foo = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
   return (T)(foo.ConvertFromInvariantString(mystring));
}
```

The overload using `Object` as parameter will not work with scalar data types.

---

**UPDATE**

It will work, but you have to write one line more :-P (and add a restriction):

```
public static T GetTfromString<T>(string mystring) where T : new()
{
    var o = new T();
    var foo = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(o);
    return (T)(foo.ConvertFromInvariantString(mystring));
}

GetTfromString<double>("10.5").Dump();
```